# Asus - Computer fan too noisy

Tags: windows-10, laptop, motherboard, fan, asus-laptop

I have a X750LN ASUS laptop (specific model : X750ln-ty043h-be) and I have some fan issues.

I tried several things:

- up-to-date drivers and bios
- sent my laptop to RMA (They changed the fan but the issue come back)
- made a clean install of Windows

Any ideas?

Here are some screenshot to provide you enough informations :

PS: I just don't understand why the motherboard is too hot : 96°C, if I believe speccy

[image: My Settings]
[image: HWmonitor Result]

Comment: 96 degrees celcius is very hot for a motherboard.  You definitely have something wrong going on - something that may be deeper than a fan issue.  That's nearly the boiling point of water. Surprised it runs.

Comment: Have you checked if the output values are the same in the the BIOS? As I can see, the temperature diode seems broken since the CPU temperature stays on 50ºC.

Comment: I just don't understand why how it is ... Any idea to find what is wrong ? In the ASUS bios, I don't find setting about what you are asking

Comment: I just added my BIOS advanced settings : nothing about the output values.

Answer (score 0):

The board reaching those temperatures is not normal. It's likely that even with the fan replacement it is working as hard as it can to cool the CPU, thus the noise. I don't think your issue was related to a bad fan.

I'd suggest sending that in for warranty repair again, that is some serious hardware failure.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. The bad thing is that I have no more warranty (the previous repair was in my last warranty month ) XD ... What it is the most strange at all, the fan is most of the time not noisy but for whatever reason (game, IDE,etc), it becomes mad and become quiet after some time

Comment: Damn :( If you feel handy enough, you could lookup a teardown video of your device and check for dust buildup. You could check your BIOS for any options to enable full speed on your fan. Also, I'd like you to try booting into a live system via USB/CD to see if it's software related

Comment: For the bios, I have only the odd interface (the odd one : https://i.stack.imgur.com/BDgR2.jpg ) ; only access to UEFI bios may help  but I didn't find how to do that on Asus to get this one : http://archive.benchmarkreviews.com/images/reviews/motherboards/P8P67-EVO/ASUS-P8P67-EVO-BIOS-6.jpg

Comment: That's really odd, you sure that second picture is actually the BIOS for your X750LN? In my experience I haven't seen that kind of environment anywhere other than ASUS desktop motherboards. If you've already flashed your BIOS to the latest update I'm afraid that's of good of options as you'll get. Did you try tinkering with that thermal option? Also, check what HWmonitor reports as temperatures

Comment: What I was showing on the second picture, my bios haven't so much options like it ^^ I added my HWmonitor result.

Comment: That is really strange that your board reads out that hot yet the other components are at reasonable temps. I wonder if the sensor broke somehow. Does it feel that hot when you touch it?

Comment: I touched it several time  Let's said 90% of the time , It isn't hot. Not a bad idea this sensor problem .... Any way to fix/bypass it ?

Comment: I'm sure there is but I've never attempted it so I couldn't offer any valuable advice. However, with it not actually feeling too hot you are probably going to be okay in the long run

Comment: If I belive the RMA guy, it should be a "FAN CONTROL" (something like that) option in the bios .... It seems the fan is controlled by mothercard sensor ...